# call parent ctor from ctor of inheriting class

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Is it valid to instead of doing this

```
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};
function Penguin(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = 2;
}
Penguin.prototype = new Animal();
var penguin = new Penguin("Tux");
penguin.sayName();
```

do that?

```
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
}
Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
    console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
};
function Penguin(name) {
    return new Animal(name, 2);
}
Penguin.prototype = new Animal();
var penguin = new Penguin("Tux");
penguin.sayName();
```

I find the second version more elegant and hoped both version were equivalent in their results, but for the second one [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/objects-ii/3/4) tells me

```
Oops, try again. Make sure to create a new Penguin instance called penguin!
```

while the first one is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to call the parent constructor:

```
function Penguin(name) {
    return new Animal(name, 2);
}
```

The correct way is as follows:

```
function Penguin(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name, 2);
}
```

The reason is because of the way `new` works:

1. Let's say you have a function called `ABC`.
2. When you execute `new ABC` JavaScript creates an instance of `ABC.prototype` and binds it to `this` inside of the function `ABC` which is why you can add properties to `this` inside `ABC`.
3. The constructor function returns `this` by default **unless** you return another object explicitly.

The reason Codecademy complains about your code is because you're returning a `new Animal(name, 2)` which is **not** an `instanceof` `Penguin`.

As I said before the correct way to call the parent constructor is to use `ParentConstructor.call(this, arg1, arg2, ...)`. In this case we are setting the `this` inside the parent constructor to the same value as `this` inside the current constructor (which is the instance created by `new`).

---

If you want to write elegant code then try this on for size:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    var instance = prototype.instance = function () {};
    constructor.prototype = instance.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}

function extend(parent, keys) {
    var supertype = keys.super = parent.prototype;
    var prototype = new supertype.instance;
    for (var key in keys) prototype[key] = keys[key];
    return defclass(prototype);
}
```

Using `defclass` and `extend` you could rewrite your code as follows:

```
var Animal = defclass({
    constructor: function (name, numLegs) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numLegs = numLegs;
    },
    sayName: function () {
        console.log("Hi my name is " + this.name);
    }
});

var Penguin = extend(Animal, {
    constructor: function (name) {
        this.super.constructor.call(this, name, 2);
    }
});

var penguin = new Penguin("Tux");
penguin.sayName();
```

How cool is that?

Comment: Wow, that is quite cool indeed. Thank you very much for this educational answer.

Comment: You create additional vars with global scope here... does this happen implicit when defining prototypes without adding the prototype to a global var as it is shown in the other answeres here?

Comment: @treeno I don't understand your question. Would you please be more lucid?

Comment: I wonder if your approach will lead to more global variables because you write var Animal = defclass(...). I think that using just a ctor-function and composing the prototype like shown in the question will create less global variables. But I'm not shure if this is true.

Comment: @treeno There are only five global variables created in my code, namely `defclass`, `extend`, `Animal`, `Penguin` and `penguin`. The only __additional__ variables are `defclass` and `extend`. The other variables are global in the the OP's question as well. However it needn't be necessary to make any of them global. You could simply wrap the code in a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and you'll never have any globals. If you're scared of there being a global leak then rest assured that my `defclass` and `extend` functions wouldn't be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is that constructor functions don't return a value. So if you call

```
new Penguin('bla')
```

it is not the function Penguin that returns the new Object, it is the *new* that returns the new Object. So if you let Penguin() return a new Object this will conflict with the new-keyword.

If you want to call the parent-constructor, you can do that as follows:

```
function Penguin(name) {
   Animal.call(this, name, 2);
}
```

Just additionally: When you assign the prototype of Animal to its sub-prototype Penguin, you call the Function in your example without its paramers. There is a cleaner way to do that:

```
Penguin.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

After that you have lost the constructor function of Penguin so you need to reassign it like this:

```
Penguin.prototype.constructor = Animal;
```

This is explained in detail here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

and
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you are NOT returning an instance of Penguin but an instance of Animal. if you want to add more functionality to penguin you need to decorate the Animal class with extra functionality.

```
function Penguin(name) {
    var self = new Animal(name, 2);
    self.penguinFunction = function (){
        //do something here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I think you loose the prototype chain by that way.

Comment: .. and you change the prototype of Animal, so all Animals will have the penguinFunction() even a protoype named Elephant that extends Animal ;-)